# Windows Vista on my Dell desktop wont start I just get a black screen saying enter password

Tags: windows-vista, boot, passwords

I have a Dell desktop running Windows Vista Basic, I turn on the machine and all I get is Enter Password with a black screen. I don't know why I am getting this so I tried turning it on and entering F2 for setup and it says the same thing enter password. I opened this and removed the password jumper then turn it back on and still getting the same thing enter password on black screen. I thought removing the jumper would reset the password and allow me to start vista and set a new password.  What can I do now to start Vista? I have data to save on this hard drive.

Comment: Open the chassis, take the CMOS battery OUT for few minutes, put it back it and try again. If it doesn't work, you sound like to have a BIOS password.

Comment: Congratulations...somebody messed with your machine and has set a BIOS password...either you figure a wait out how to reset the BIOS (see r0cas answer), or you drug the guy who did it and hit him with a $5 wrench until he tells you the password.

Comment: Hahahaha! funny

Comment: Somehow you have a bios password set on your computer.  Ask whoever maintains your computer, they will probably know what happened.  That, or it is a virus.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open the chassis, take the CMOS battery out for few minutes (or hours...), put it back in and try again.

If it doesn't work, you can also check for jumpers on the motherboard... Please check your motherboard model and check online for some info about jumpers... If necessary

Comment: Ok I reset the jumpers the battery would not come up so now that I have reset the jumpers I turn it on and it says CMOS checksum error - Defaults loaded press F1 to continue  F2 enter setup 
Which shall I choose F1 or F2?

Comment: Probably F2, because you'll have to reset the clock.